# Firebase web push notification not working messaging.onMessage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, web-notifications

I have configured web push notifications to my PWA ionic 4 app. The web push notifications are working like a charm when the tab is switched i.e in background or other than my app.

**The issue is when the tab is active I get the push messaging inside application section of chrome inspection but there is no notification fired.**

Below is the code:

**app.component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
   await this.notificationsService.requestPermission();
   });
}
```

**notifications.service.ts**

```
export class NotificationsService {
  init(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(
    registration => {
      // Don't crash an error if messaging not supported
      if (!firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      const messaging = firebase.messaging();

      // Register the Service Worker
      messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

      // Initialize your VAPI key
      messaging.usePublicVapidKey(environment.firebase.vapidKey);


      // Listen to messages when your app is in the foreground
      messaging.onMessage(payload => {
        console.log("Payload is here", payload);
      });
      // Optional and not covered in the article
      // Handle token refresh
      messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
        messaging
          .getToken()
          .then((refreshedToken: string) => {
            console.log(refreshedToken);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      });

      resolve();
    },
    err => {
      reject(err);
    }
  );
});
}
```

So when notificatoin is triggered if the application tab is open in chrome is should call `console.log` inside `messaging.onMessage` but it doesn't get executed.
I am using *firebase version of 7.8.0* in `firebase-messaging-sw.js`.

Comment: Might want to checkout https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2181

Answer (score -1):

When your application in Foreground, your app will not going to receive notification with `messaging` observable but it will be emitted on `messages` observable.

So you should subscribe it like this

```
firebase.messages.subscribe((message: any) => {
        if (message.notification) {
          // Show your notification from here
        }
      });
```